Why doesn't Poetry use the version of Python I tell it to use?
My project has the following in the pyproject.toml:
# [...]
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
# [...]

As I didn't touch this project since a long time, I have removed my virtual environment so I can start from a clean one, but I can't tell Poetry to use Python 3.12:
> poetry env info

Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.6
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/jerome/.../.venv
Executable:     /Users/jerome/.../.venv/bin/python
Valid:          True

System
Platform:   darwin
OS:         posix
Python:     3.9.6
Path:       /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9
Executable: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9

> poetry env use 3.12
Creating virtualenv .../Users/jerome/.../.venv-coL99X6--py3.12 in /Users/jerome/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs
Using virtualenv: /Users/jerome/.../.venv

> poetry env info

Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.6
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/jerome/.../.venv
Executable:     /Users/jerome/.../.venv/bin/python
Valid:          True

System
Platform:   darwin
OS:         posix
Python:     3.9.6
Path:       /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9
Executable: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9

I have tried different alternatives of the poetry env use command, like telling it the exact path to the Python 3.12 executable (in Homebrew's path). With the same result.
What did I miss?

Do you have poetry.lock file? If you do, try to remove it. It may help

@ArtemStrogin just tried to delete the lock file, but I have exactly the same issue

You need to make sure that Python3.12 is properly installed.
python3.12 --version
which python3.12

and then if it is not, install it.
brew install python@3.12

If it is already installed, but you're Poetry is still not recognizing it, you can pass the full path to Poetry from which python3.12.
poetry env use $(which python3.12) # or
poetry env use /path/to/python3.12

Another issue could be that it is just trying to reuse the old venv so you can try removing it.
poetry env remove python3.9

